# Push a child of a Column upwards in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is a Row inside a Column.  I want to move the Row top of the screen.

What is the way to do it?

```
return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          
          new Expanded(
            child: Row(
              
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                  ),
                ),

                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                ),
                
              ],
            )
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you wnat to switch Row and Column, or move the Row up in the column tree (Because in your example, you only have one child in the column, so you can't move it anywhere within the column). Depending on what you actually want to do, you can store your children in a variable and with a GestureDetector, you can change the order of the childrens in the setState, so the new order will be reflected with the next build.

Comment: Okay, besides the row there is one more child which is an image. I thought it won't be important to show it here. I want to reduce space between the row and that image. Also I want to push both of them upwards towards the top of the screen. @Xavjer

Comment: Basically whatever is in this column I want to move it towards upside of the screen. Currently it is shown in center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move that row upward by adding this
to the row

```
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

this will take it as up as possible.

then you can change it as you desire by adding a sizedBox to the top position in column

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 200,),

          new Expanded( ..... )
```

Answer (score 1):

please try with this

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          height: 70, width: 70),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                        height: 70, width: 70),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ])
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1st column widget have on child and that is `Expanded`, and it will take as most spaces as it can get. In this case it is taking full height and width. You may have question now then why it is on center? Because default `Row` `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`

By default, `Column` `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,` so we don't have to worry about aligning at top level.

To know more about layout, visit

- [ui/layout](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout)
- [Column-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)