# Reduce space between Column widgets (using Expanded) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see, here is a Column.
Column contains an Expanded Row.
Column contains a GestureDetector containing an Image.

There is a huge gap between the children of this Column. Is it because of `Expanded`?

If yes, then when should Expanded be used and what should be used instead of that in this case?

```
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(

        children: <Widget>[

          SizedBox( height: 220,),
          new Expanded(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                  ),
                ),

                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                  child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                ),
                
              ],
            )
          ),

          GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Yes, it is because of the ```Expanded``` widget.  the space at the top of the page is covered by the ```SizedBox```. There is an image at the bottom of the page. The remaining space in between these two is occupied by the ```Expanded``` widget in the middle.

Comment: Expanded == "take as much space as you can"

Comment: To avoid this, you can whether remove the expanded widget or replace it with the ```Flexible``` widget

Comment: yeah flexible is great solution @EhsanAskari

Comment: you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68907525/10157127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to like this, just remove your `expanded` and replace with `Flexible` as Ehsan said

```
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox( height: 220,),
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, // here you need to change
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                    ),
                  ),

                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                      });
                    },
                    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', height: 70, width: 70),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
```

output:

[image]